# how to decrypt the encrypted data in php mysql using aes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, encryption, aes

I have `key_id`, `key_verification`, `confirm_key`, and `key_status` in my verification table.

I managed to encrypt my `key_verification` into my database by using AES:

```
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO verification (key_verification, key_status) VALUES ((AES_ENCRYPT('bhadana', '" . $key_verification . "')), '" . $key_status . "')";
```

However I have problem when trying to decrypt it back. This is the code I’m using:

```
 $sql4="SELECT * FROM verification WHERE key_verification = AES_ENCRYPT ('bhadana', '" . $key_verification . "')";
 $query4 = mysql_query($sql4) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
 $num_rows4 = mysql_num_rows($query4);
 $check4 = mysql_fetch_array($query4);

 $sql3= "SELECT AES_DECRYPT (key_verification, '" . $key_verification . "') as encrypted from verification";
 $query3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
 $num_rows3 = mysql_num_rows($query3);
 $check3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3);
```

I know the SQL is wrong but I don't know how to join the SQL. And if there's anything that I need to add in the code?

I am new to encryption and I hope someone can help me with this.

**EDIT:** The error is "undefined key_verification"

Comment: Try `SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT (key_verification, '" . $key_verification . "')AS CHAR(100)) as encrypted from verification`

Comment: @Mihai it's not working. oh and the error is undefined key_verification in both sql

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a MySQL error? Could you possibly be getting a PHP error?

Comment: @OllieJones this is what the error said ; Undefined variable: key_verification

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code is trying to use the variable $key_verification, but it seems to be undefined.

Your example statement, formatted for readability, says

```
$sql3= "SELECT AES_DECRYPT (key_verification, '" . 
       $key_verification .
       "') as encrypted from verification";
```

For this to work you need the variable $key_verification already defined, or you'll get the `undefined` message from PHP.

Pro-tip: Using encryption with the old insecure mysql_ API is like putting an expensive security lock on your window while leaving your front door wide open.

Comment: i solved the error. but now why is my decrypted data is ÜýéÂé3ÿ;Hj‚iˆ intead of going back to the original data 5437?